# Check for Empty Input

Tags: java, file-io

I'm writing a Java program to parse through a text file, line by line, containing lists of numbers. However, not all lines contain numbers. I was wondering how I could skip over those lines without numbers. The text file looks like this.

```
1 0 > 1 6 2 6 3 6
1 1 > 4 -1
1 2 > 8 -1
1 3 > 9 -1
1 4 > 1 -1 5 -1 6 -1
1 5 > 
1 6 > 7 -1 8 -1
1 7 > 
1 8 > 7 -1
0 9 >
```

I have a `for loop` that goes through each line and processes the numbers to the left of the `>` sign, however, whenever I reach lines with no numbers right of `>`, I get a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the code I'm having trouble with. It occurs when I try adding children to my `tokens[i]` state.

```
File file = new File("data.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
HashMap<String, Integer> states = new HashMap<String, Character>(10);

while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" |>"); 

    for(int i = 3; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if(tokens[i] == null | tokens[i + 1] == null | tokens[i] == "")
            break;
        if(i % 2 != 0)
            tokens[1].children.add(states.get(tokens[i]));
    }
}
```

`State` is a class I've created which contains an `ArrayList` called `children` in which I add different states to

Comment: something wrong with `if--else` statement?

Comment: Post your exception with full stack trace and the part of code it points to.

Comment: Consider using regex to do a digit check?

Comment: Check first whether the line you are trying to parse is null. `if (line != null){//logic}`

Comment: I need to check if a certain element in the `String[] tokens` is null, not the entire line.